# Confluence REST API Basic Authentication

Tags: java, http, postman, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Currently I'm working on a Java Tool that should Update a Confluence Server Page.
Using Curl everything works like a charm, but when using Postman or Java-Code (HttpClient Java11) i get an

> HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized

Resonse.

Using curl with following statement

> curl --basic -u user:password -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@test.json" [https://confluence.xxx.com/confluence/rest/api/content/{pageID}](https://confluence.xxx.com/confluence/rest/api/content/%7BpageID%7D)

it works just fine.

The following Java Code:

```
String encode = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((confluence_username + ":" + confluence_password).getBytes());


            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                        .uri(URI.create(endpoint))
                        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encode)
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .PUT(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(inputJson))
                        .build();
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            System.out.println(response.statusCode());
            System.out.println(response.body());
```

with "endpoint" being the Confluence Page-URI, gives a 401 Response.

And also in Postman the Response is always 401.

**I rechecked the Login details and they are 100% correct. Furthermore I checked, before running the program/Postman, if the account needed a Captcha refresh.**

```
GET https://confluence.xxx.com/confluence/rest/api/content/xxx: {
  "Network": {
    "addresses": {
      "local": {
        "address": "1.2.3.4",
        "family": "IPv4",
        "port": 50668
      },
      "remote": {
        "address": "1.2.3.4",
        "family": "IPv4",
        "port": 443
      }
    },
    "tls": {
      "reused": true,
      "authorized": true,
      "authorizationError": null,
      "cipher": {
        "name": "XXXX",
        "standardName": "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "version": "TLSv1/SSLv3"
      },
      "protocol": "TLSv1.2",
      "ephemeralKeyInfo": {},
      "peerCertificate": {
        "subject": {
          "country": "X",
          "stateOrProvince": "X",
          "locality": "X",
          "organization": "X",
          "organizationalUnit": "X",
          "commonName": "X",
          "alternativeNames": "X, X"
        },
        "issuer": {
          "country": "X",
          "organization": "X",
          "commonName": "X"
        },
        "validFrom": "Mar  6 10:34:33 2020 GMT",
        "validTo": "Mar  6 10:44:00 2022 GMT",
        "fingerprint": "X",
        "serialNumber": "X"
      }
    }
  },
  "Request Headers": {
    "x-atlassian-token": "no-check",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Basic XXX",
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.28.3",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "postman-token": "42958f39-7fad-4e37-b2d1-657343e45403",
    "host": "confluence.XXX.com",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "cookie": "JSESSIONID=1DSF345jl3h45kD82"
  },
  "Request Body": "",
  "Response Headers": {
    "date": "Wed, 11 Aug 2021 06:36:28 GMT",
    "server": "Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips",
    "x-asen": "SEN-4272739",
    "x-seraph-loginreason": "AUTHENTICATION_DENIED",
    "www-authenticate": "OAuth realm=\"https%3A%2F%2Fconfluence.xxx.com%2Fconfluence\"",
    "content-type": "text/html;charset=utf-8",
    "content-language": "en",
    "content-length": "437",
    "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100",
    "connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000"
  },
  "Response Body": "<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized</title><style type=\"text/css\">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized</h1></body></html>"
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did curl work? Did you try to endcode username:password in other tool then compare to `encode` string in java or postman?

Comment: Curl worked. Yes I tried encode de login details with other tools and the result was the same as the "encode" String

Comment: Could you provide console log of postman and request log in java? One case I've encountered, the problem was `http` and `https`.

Comment: I added the postman log to the Questions text

Comment: You can try using a personal access token https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/using-personal-access-tokens-1026032365.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue with making HTTPS request with postman. make sure you have disable the HTTPS in postman.

Postman >> Preferences >> SSL certificate verification OFF.

For further detail: [sending certificate with HTTPS request using post](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)